# regex - extract text between 5th and 7th occurrence of a character

Tags: regex

Given the following String:

```
AT7*AF*NS***20130925*1216*CT~
```

How do I pull out "20130925*1216"?

Anything in between each * delimiter can be 0..n alphanumeric characters. So I essentially want the string between the 5th and 7th * character...

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ Figure it out.

Comment: downvote is uncalled for. I posted the question because I am horrible at regex and just can't get through the mental block. Would appreciate some expert help here as I have not seen regex do what I am asking here...

Comment: `^([^*]*[*]){5}([^*]*[*][^*]*[*])`

Comment: Yeah I don't know who downvoted you. Definitely uncalled for tho.

Comment: very close @abiessu. Your regex gives me the entire line up to the 7th occurance of "*". I only want the text between 5-7.

Comment: @ZackArgyle: I prefer http://rubular.com - It is not obvious to me how to get captures at regexpal (or maybe you can't and I was searching in vain)

Comment: Rubular is good too. To get matches just put examples in the lower box, and your regex in the upper box. It automatically highlights matches.

Comment: @DomenicD: my intent was that you would use the second capture group, since I always forget the syntax for non-capture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[^*]*\*){5}([^*]*\*[^*]+)
```

The first capture group.

Comment: beautiful. Thanks so much. You folks who understand regex as well as your own native language astound me!

Comment: @DomenicD.: I didn't get the native language point. You don't even know what mine is :)

Comment: what I mean that you know the regex "language" as good as your own native tongue (whatever it is). It just comes easy to you which amazes me.